# How to pass header in another response in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have `response.header` in `header`. I want to pass that header to another response.

so, my approach is to save the header in shared preference and then retrieve it.

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString('header', response.headers.toString());
```

and then retrieve it

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String? head = prefs.getString('header');
Map<String, String> authHeaders = jsonDecode(head!);
```

but `authHeders` is giving me an error.

```
Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
```

`header` before saving to SharedPreferences.

```
{connection: keep-alive, set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=nBYdTZyY2FrQUl0RitDemxmdnNVMVRacC9XcENyV3pJankiLCJtYWMiOiJkOTRmZWMwYjYyMDdjMjAwNjBmZTJmZDYyNGYzYzI0YTVjMDNmN2VjZjc3MzZkM2UzNzc1MTk2ZjViOGE0MGMyIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Mon, 01-Aug-2022 08:56:00 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; samesite=lax,laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Iko1U1ZkejhNWVo3b0twb0pwdS9QMVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVUxyTFVmMm9XSG95VHd6cGxCVThqSExvSzJQWmQ2WWRMRGpoT0xsVjExdHl1M0xnZ2xGZjd2WDRVdHRqa1J4TU4rRjByakFoSUNHT2lPTGVUb0Z4aHNhWjRleTM0TnBjakRPRzc4WkZVWDMvTzdqNlpoVTBCRWRsOTlwcHIvNFQiLCJtYWMiOiI0MTRhMjRkNGY3Njg0ZDI4NjU1MzFmZjI2M2FkOTA5NDc4ZWJhYzhiZTA5MTFkZTQ2ZmJlY2UxNzBlZjc3MTc3IiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax, cache-control: no-cache, private, date: Mon, 01 Aug 2022 06:56:00 GMT, vary: Accept-Encoding, content-encoding: gzip, cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC, report-to: {"endpoint .......
```

`header` after retrieving it.

```
{connection: keep-alive, set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=nBYdTZyY2FrQUl0RitDemxmdnNVMVRacC9XcENyV3pJankiLCJtYWMiOiJkOTRmZWMwYjYyMDdjMjAwNjBmZTJmZDYyNGYzYzI0YTVjMDNmN2VjZjc3MzZkM2UzNzc1MTk2ZjViOGE0MGMyIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Mon, 01-Aug-2022 08:56:00 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; samesite=lax,laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Iko1U1ZkejhNWVo3b0twb0pwdS9QMVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVUxyTFVmMm9XSG95VHd6cGxCVThqSExvSzJQWmQ2WWRMRGpoT0xsVjExdHl1M0xnZ2xGZjd2WDRVdHRqa1J4TU4rRjByakFoSUNHT2lPTGVUb0Z4aHNhWjRleTM0TnBjakRPRzc4WkZVWDMvTzdqNlpoVTBCRWRsOTlwcHIvNFQiLCJtYWMiOiI0MTRhMjRkNGY3Njg0ZDI4NjU1MzFmZjI2M2FkOTA5NDc4ZWJhYzhiZTA5MTFkZTQ2ZmJlY2UxNzBlZjc3MTc3IiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax, cache-control: no-cache, private, date: Mon, 01 Aug 2022 06:56:00 GMT, vary: Accept-Encoding, content-encoding: gzip, cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC, report-to: {"endpoint .......
```

Yes, both are same.

This is how I am saving header.

```
  login(String phn, String password) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await getLocation();
    String uri = "$baseUrl/User_Login";
    try {
      http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(uri), headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }, body: {
        "number": phn,
        "password": password,
        "long": long,
        "lati": lati
      });
      print(response.headers);
      prefs.setString('header', response.headers.toString());
      return json.decode(response.body);
    } catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  }
```

This is how I am retrieving it and passing it to another response.

```
  getData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? head = prefs.getString('header');
    print("headers");
    print(head);
    Map<String, String> authHeaders = jsonDecode($head!);
    // print("authHeaders");
    // print(authHeaders.toString());
    String uri = "$baseUrlUser/user_bal";
    try {
      http.Response response =
          await http.get(Uri.parse(uri), headers: authHeaders);
      return json.decode(response.body);
    } catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello, could you show how the headers look?

Comment: Are the response that you want to pass that header in the same scope that the request?

Comment: May you print the headers before save it into the shared preferences, and after retrieving it?

Answer (score 0):

The common issue in Flutter when parsing Json data is about the type of request and it's encoding.

Even if you may post the complete source code, at least, the relevant one to your problem, like how you're performing the request, your error probably comes on how you ask for data to the remote.

If you're trying to parse the response as Json, you must specifically add the `application/json;charset=UTF-8` in your headers.

But, if you read this line in your source code:
`prefs.setString('header', response.headers.toString());`
you're saving the `headers` as string in the `header` key. This means, that the headers are usually represented in most standars as `Map` datastructures, so you're asking for retrive as a String in `decode(...)` a probably bad formatted data.

The solution it's pretty straightfoward. Save the header(s) that your interested one by one, and then retrieve them by key, and the format should be ok to use the `jsonDecode`.

Edit:
getting directly your code to exemplify as requested by the OP how to get them individually. We will take the `Accept` header as example, as it's also the unique provide in the example code.

```
login(String phn, String password) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await getLocation();
    String uri = "$baseUrl/User_Login";
    try {
      http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(uri), headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }, body: {
        "number": phn,
        "password": password,
        "long": long,
        "lati": lati
      });
      prefs.setString('header', response.headers.get('Accept'));
      return json.decode(response.body);
    } catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  }
```

Then, you only must retrieve it by key:

```
getData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? head = prefs.getString('Accept');

    Map<String, String> authHeaders = new Map();
    authHeaders['Accept'] = head!; 

    String uri = "$baseUrlUser/user_bal";
    try {
      http.Response response =
          await http.get(Uri.parse(uri), headers: authHeaders);
      return json.decode(response.body);
    } catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  }
```

The unique difference is that you're not storing a completly Map as a String as you do in the example, you're saving the keys that you desire as what they are, Strings. Parsing JSON it's alwaya a quite sensible action, so the more granularity over the pieces you take, the best results.

Comment: @SandeepSharma as I pointed in the answer, the most probably cause of your issue is the fact of saving a `Map` like struct as String, and then try to parse them back from that String to Json. 

Instead saving the whole headers, get every header you're interested and saving them one by one in `SharedPreferences`. Then, retrieve them by key, initialize a new map and push them. Then parse the new map with the old headers to your request.

Comment: So, how to pass the header to another response?

Comment: @SandeepSharma code edited with code explanation